# Removing the added border from JTextField and bringing it back to normal

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, border, jtextfield

Please have a look at the below code

```
Border border = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.RED, 1);
introducerFeesTxt.setBorder(border);
```

I used this code to create a line border for the `JTextField`. However now I need to remove it and replace it's normal view. Below is what I tried.

```
introducerFeesTxt.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK, 1));
```

That code above again created a border which is not similar to other normal JTextFields. Below is a screenshot.

[image]

You can clearly see the differnece between the "Normal" `JTextField` and the JTextField with the added border. How can I reset it to be "normal" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the original border from the L&F (Look and Feel).

```
Border border = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.RED, 1);
introducerFeesTxt.setBorder(border);
// some operation

introducerFeesTxt.setBorder(UIManager.getBorder("TextField.border"));
```

Answer (score 3):

You could keep the original border in a variable before change it and then use this border to set it back to its original state:

```
Border originalBorder;
...
JTextField textField = new JTextField(20);
originalBorder = textField.getBorder();
// here you can safely change text field's border
```

Of course the scope of this `originalBorder` variable should be wide enough to use it when needed (f.e.: class member).

**Note:** Please note this approach is independent of the [PLAF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pluggable_look_and_feel) used by your application.